# InvalidDataContractException error while saving IsolatedStorage

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am developing an app for Windows Phone 8.0 in VS2012

and I have in my SetProfile.xaml Page an `IsolatedStorage`

**SetProfile.xaml**

```
public partial class SetProfile : PhoneApplicationPage
{
 private int Indexer;
    private int age;
    IsolatedStorageSettings Profile = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;

private void create_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (FirstName.Text != "" && LastName.Text != "" && Age.Text!= "")
        {
           age = Convert.ToInt32(Age.Text);
            //catch (FormatException exc) { };
            if (age > 5 || age < 120)
            {
                Player player = new Player();

                player.FirstName = FirstName.Text;
                player.LastName = LastName.Text;
                try
                {
                    player.Age = Convert.ToInt32(Age.Text);
                }
                catch (FormatException)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Invalid Age");
                    Age.Text = "";
                    return;
                }
                player.Rank = 1;
                player.RankDescreption = "Beginner";
                player.Points = 0;

                Indexer = GetCurrentIndex();
                string key = string.Format("player{0}", Indexer);

                if (Indexer == 1)
                {             
                    player.ID = Indexer;
                    Profile.Add("CurrentProfile", player);
                     Profile.Add("PlayersCount",(int)1);
                }
                else
                    Profile["CurrentProfile"] = player;

                player.ID = Indexer;
                Profile.Add(key, player);

                int count = (int)Profile["PlayersCount"];
                count++;
                Profile["PlayersCount"] = count;

                    Profile.Save();


                NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Avatars.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
            }

            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Age is Invalid");
                create_Click(null, null);
            }
        }
}
```

when i debug the app , it crashes on the line `Profile.Save();`
with `'System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException'`

I don't know why it happened , i've been working on my app a long time , and the code was working , but today when i added a class (`Game`) to the project (related to Player class) , this error started to appear

Further information about the class i added:  in this question i posted a little while ago: [AccessViolationException while adding item to a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23697956/accessviolationexception-while-adding-item-to-a-list/23698002?noredirect=1#23698002)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

InvalidDataContractException means that you need to tag what ever you're serializing with the `[DataContractAttribute]` attribute.

Subsequently you will also need to tag any members of your object with `[DataMember]` in order for the serializer to recognize it.

Good news, if you want an easier way to serialize objects to the isolated storage I built it already and its free. It's called EZ_iso.dll I have posted about it a number of times on the stack exchange and it has been widely adopted among both new and seasoned devs.

An example would be

```
[DataContractAttribute]
public class MainPageSettings
{        
    [DataMember]         
    publicString yourSetting1 {get; set;}
    [DataMember]         
    public List<Object> yourSetting2 {get; set;}
    [DataMember]         
    public int yourSetting3 {get; set;}
    [DataMember]         
    public Boolean yourSetting4 {get; set;}
}
```

Now you can save your data and retrieve it with a single line of code

To serialize it (after its been initialized)

```
EZ_Iso.IsolatedStorageAccess.SaveFile("MPageSettings",yourSettingsObj);
```

Then to deserialize it

```
MainPageSettings yourSettingsObj = (MainPageSettings)EZ_Iso.IsolatedStorageAccess.GetFile("MPageSettings",typeof(MainPageSettings));
```

It's that easy.

You can find it [here EZ_Iso](http://anthonyrussell.info/postpage.php?name=2)

Comment: Thanks , but where i should add these lines of code?

Comment: But why it was working at first , and then it stopped working

Comment: You didn't post the relevant code so I told you what was causing the error and offered an alternative solution.

Comment: But listen , i used `Save()` alot of times in my project ! , and the others work good , only this one doesn't work !

Comment: I understand that you don't understand why it isn't working. I got that. What I am telling you is if you want a real chance of fixing it, due to your low level of experience, implement what you are trying to do differently. You didn't post relevant code. I told you what was causing the error AND I gave you an alternative. That's the best you're going to get off of here. No one here is a mind reader.

Comment: Okay i'll try , and how i can i add this dll to my project?

Comment: Wow ! , I excluded the Game.cs class from the project , and now everything works well , does it help you to find the problem now ?

Comment: If everything works well then why would I need to find your problem? @GabourX

Comment: It's okay i decided to delete the class , and i apperchiate your work on the dll , thanks anyways